# How to store a string into a variable that includes a $ using linux bash

Tags: linux, variables, expect

I am attempting to send a password to a remote server using a `bash` script. This worked fine until we were required to change the passwords to more complex passwords and one of the new passwords included a `$` character (i.e. `P@$sw0rd`).

I have included the snippet that is no longer working:

```
password="'P@$sw0rd'"

spawn ssh "$deviceType@$device"
expect {
  "*no)?" {send "yes\r"}
  "*assword:" {send "$password\r"}
  "*assword:" {send "$password\r"}
}
```

Every time it sends the password, the remote system attempts to find the variable `$sw0rd`.

I know the problem is with the `$` character in the password itself, but is there a way to do this without changing this one password on all of our remote servers to one that does not include the `$` character?

I have tried different ways to store the `$` character:

```
password='P@$sw0rd'
password=P@$sw0rd
password="'P@\$sw0rd'"
password="P@\$sw0rd"
password='P@\$sw0rd'
password=P@\$sw0rd
```

None of these have worked.

Please, help.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a problem of the **remote system**

Comment: Can you include more of the code? If your code is actually `password="whatever";  expect << eof;  spawn ssh "$deviceType@$device"; ...; eof` then that makes a huge difference. Currently the code appears to be partially Bash and partially TCL, and therefore not runnable or representative of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

As you use `spawn` command there is a chance that you actually have `expect` script and not `bash` script. This should work in `expect`:

```
set password P@\$sw0rd
```

Of course you also have to use `expect` to run that script, either by adding `#!/usr/bin/env expect` at the top or using `expect` directly in the terminal: `expect <SCRIPT>`

Comment: Or, use Tcl's non-interpolating quotes: `set password {P@$sw0rd}`

Answer (score 0):

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk has your answer.

You need to use `exp_continue` to get your login to work though:

```
spawn ssh "$deviceType@$device"
expect {
  "*no)?" {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
  "*assword:" {send "$password\r"; exp_continue}
  "*your prompt pattern here"
}
# ... carry on with the script
```

`exp_continue` allows you to stay in the current expect command and continue to look for other patterns. You do need something else to expect to allow you to break out.